# ¿Cuál es el origen de "mecachis"?

Tags: etimología, españa, interjecciones, insultos

Seguro que lo habéis oído: alguien se enfada y suelta un...

> **Mecachis** en la mar

Como eufemismo de cosas bastante más explícitas como:

> Me cago en dios

El DRAE ya lo recoge:

> [**mecachis**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Oi1ySHX)
>   1. interj. eufem. coloq. U. para expresar extrañeza o contrariedad. *Mecachis, está lloviendo*. U. t. en exprs. como mecachis en la mar con el mismo significado.
>   mecachis en algo o alguien
>   1. expr. eufem. coloq. U. para expresar desprecio o rechazo hacia esa persona o esa cosa. *Mecachis en mi suerte*.

Y en distintos foros hablan de su uso eufemístico. Sin embargo, no encuentro el origen de la palabra. ¿Alguien lo sabe?

Ah, nótese que no sé vosotros pero yo ya uso *cachis* a secas como interjección absoluta:

> — Hoy no hay partida...
>   —¡Cachis!

Comment: @DGaleano ¿no se usa en Colombia? El DRAE no especifica región, por lo que pensé que sería común en todo el ámbito lingüístico del castellano.

Comment: Jamás la había oído. Empezando porque "Me cag* en..." nunca se usa por estos lados y nos suena absolutamente terrible. Yo se que en España es frecuente pero les recomiendo que si se encuentran alguna vez por hispanoamérica no la usen. Ahora, si usan "mecachis" casi estoy seguro que van a tener que explicar que significa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Desconozco el origen de la palabra (presente en el diccionario desde 1927 con el significado de "caramba"), pero puedo darte una suposición. Iba a escribir esto como comentario, pero creo que puede ser una explicación plausible. Desde 1884 existe en el diccionario de la RAE la palabra:

> **[chis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8tAplNy)**
>
> Voz onomat.
>
> 1. interj. U. para llamar a alguien.
> 2. interj. coloq. **[chitón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8ukFTxA)**. U. acompañada con algún ademán, como el de poner el dedo índice en los labios.

"Chitón", por supuesto, es una "interjección usada para imponer silencio". Luego es muy probable que el origen sea sencillamente un diálogo de este tipo:

> —¡Me ca...!
>
> —¡Chis!

Y simplemente a partir de ahí la expresión se abreviara en "mecachis", ya que uno mismo se mandaba a callar al intentar decir la expresión. En el [fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) de la RAE, si se busca "mechachis", la [ficha 13](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MECACHIS/00000319.pdf) (PDF), registrada en 1924, parece confirmar mi teoría (al menos, la parte del "me ca..."):

> Es una de tantas voces hipocritonas, eufemismos con que se terminan voces mal comenzadas [...]. ¡Mecachis! nació de la locución *me ca...* amputada antes de terminar puercamente, y trocado su final en *chis*, dando origen a un vocablo sin sentido castellano.

Esta [otra ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MECACHIS/00000322.pdf) (PDF) lo registra separado ("me cachis"). Otras fichas recogen expresiones como "mechachis en dies/diez". Por último, existe otra palabra con la misma terminación, usada como interjección en Guatemala y que podría tener un origen similar: **[puchis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UYxaPfb)** ("usada para expresar sorpresa o susto").

Como añadido, comentar que los primeros casos que encuentro son de 1870, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España. Nótese la expresión escrita por separado y con *cachis* en cursiva:

> —¡Cielos! añadió la duquesa estremecida.
> —¡Me *cachis*! debió añadir Víctor Manuel aparte.
>
> **Gil Blas (Madrid).** 13/1/1870, [página 1](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003844918&page=1&search=mecachis%20%22me%20cachis%22&lang=es).

> Es claro; ¿cómo habia de tener fondos el clero para hacer funciones de iglesia, si los necesitaba para hacer funciones de pólvora?
> ¡*Me cachis* en esos curas!...
>
> **La Iberia (Madrid).** 30/4/1870, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001313871&page=4&search=mecachis&lang=es).

Comment: ¡Fantástica respuesta, Carlos! Tiene mucho sentido

Comment: Vaya, yo pensaba que imitaba un "estornudo para interrumpir" la palabrota. Mec... ¡achís! Pero sí, esto tiene más sentido.

Answer (score -1):

Apócope de "me cache en die" a su vez eufemismo de "me cago en dios" que se expresa para significar sorpresa, disgusto, imposibilidad.